# How to get H:i:s from minutes?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have a value `15 min` from which i need to get `H:i:s`. Tried `date('H:i:s', strtotime('15 min'))` but it returns `15:23:47` and i need `00:15:00`.

Comment: Any feedback for the guys who have provided answers for you?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<?php

    $time = "15 min";
    echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("midnight + " . $time));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many solutions for getting the H:i:s from minutes.

---

```
<?php
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("midnight + 15 min"));
```

?>

---

```
<?php
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("today + 15 min"));
```

?>

---

```
<?php
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("tomorrow + 15 min"));
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Your value of '15 mins', in this case is not a time, it is a time interval and is most appropriately represented by the [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) class. Using the right tool makes the job very simple:-

```
$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 min');
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Output:-

> 00:15:00

You could get the same output in one line if you are a fan of that kind of thing:-

```
echo \DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 min')->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

However the first option has the advantage of keeping the DateInterval instance available for further use.